# Bluetooth Low Energy API Windows 8

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to write a Desktop application for Windows 8, that can communicate with Bluetooth Low Energy devices. After my Research I think this is only possible for Windows apps but not for a Desktop application because there are no APIs. Is there a way to use the APIs for the Windows apps in a Desktop application?

Thanks

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

namespace WinRTNutzungVS2013
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                Initialize().GetAwaiter();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fehler");
            }
        }

        double convertTemperatureData(byte[] temperatureData)
        {
            UInt32 mantissa = ((UInt32)temperatureData[3] << 16 | ((UInt32)temperatureData[2] << 8) | ((UInt32)temperatureData[1]));

            Int32 exponent = (Int32)temperatureData[4];

            return mantissa * Math.Pow(10.0, exponent);
        }

        private async Task Initialize()
        {
            var themometerServices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.HealthThermometer), null);
            GattDeviceService firstThermometerService = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(themometerServices[0].Id);
            tbServices.Text = "Using service: " + themometerServices[0].Name;
            GattCharacteristic thermometerCharacteristic = firstThermometerService.GetCharacteristics(GattCharacteristicUuids.TemperatureMeasurement)[0];
            thermometerCharacteristic.ValueChanged += temperatureMeasurementChanged;
            await thermometerCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
        }

        void temperatureMeasurementChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            byte[] temperatureData = new byte[eventArgs.CharacteristicValue.Length];
            Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(eventArgs.CharacteristicValue).ReadBytes(temperatureData);
            var temperatureValue = convertTemperatureData(temperatureData);
            tbTemperature.Text = temperatureValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to WinRT API (Windows Apps) from desktop applications. Just follow the steps in following link:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

But be aware that you need Windows 8.1 in order to use BLE capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. But when I do it like that, I always get the error: 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattCommunicationStatus>'  have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'?

Comment: This is because you need Windows 8.1 to use the BLE capabilities. It does not work for Windows 8.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I'm using Windows 8.1 and I get the error anyway :(

Comment: After I followed the steps to use the WinRT APIs, I'm using exactly the same code to retrieve data from BLE devices from the MSDN Website ( [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn264584.aspx) )

Comment: In the blog, the TargetPlatformVersion is set to 8.0. Did you modify this to 8.1, since you're using Windows 8.1 ?.

Comment: Yes I set it to 8.1 :)

Comment: Now I have fixed the problem :) I have used the wrong version of visual studio ;) 
The code compiles, but the program doesn't show the bluetooth low Energy devices next to the pc :(

Comment: Are you connected to the device using Bluetooth settings in Windows ?

Comment: Yes I'm paired with the device I want to find ;) I will post my code, so maybe you can tell me what's wrong :)